# Angular4 Not running inside zone after 20 minutes up to 60 minutes

Tags: javascript, angular

Okay, I have a strange situation.

I have two components A and B.

On page load, Component A loads. The user sits on Component A for more than 20 minutes up to 60 minutes. At the 60 minute mark, the user clicks Next, which destroys Component A and initializes Component B. They take whatever actions on Component B, hit save, and in a failure condition, the modal does not pop.

However, as soon as the user clicks (assuming the http request has completed), the modal pops, meaning Angular's change detection has run and picked up the changes.

```
this.zone.run(() => {
    let success: boolean;
    this.service.httpRequest(params).then(response => {
        if (response.someCondition) {
            //do a thing
        } else {
            // POP Modal here. Will not work somewhere between 20 minutes 60 minutes.
        }
        this.ChangeDetector.detectChanges();
    });
});
```

I tried adding `zone.run` and `detectChanges()`. This has no effect. All other pieces of the component work.

Comment: Currently you're the only person who knows what happens inside your application and is capable of debugging it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary here.

Comment: @estus, I suppose I was hoping someone would have some advice or had heard about possible memory leaks that would cause the zone to detach or not to run.

Comment: Considering that Zone patches each and every API spot that can trigger asynchronous changes, this can be literally anything. Sorry, no easy way to solve this. This may be a PITA to debug even with a complete example that can replicate the issue.